# Set .button class for all buttons in foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to set `.button` class by default for all html buttons?

Foundation has styling for buttons only with class `.button`, but in my app there are a lot of buttons, so maybe I can set that styling for all of them without adding `.button` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You could either edit the css/sass files and apply the styles to `button` directly rather than `.button` though this may cause problems with specificity.

b) If you are using the scss/sass version of the framework you could use the `extends` property. This will mean all `button` elements inherit the styles of `.button` class

```
button {
  @extend .button;
}
```

You can get the sass version here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html

details of the `@extend property can be found here: http://sass-lang.com/guide

c) Alternatively you could run some javascript to add the class to all the buttons.

The truth is I think it would be less desirable then actually adding the classes properly but I assume there is a good reason why this is not an option.

Here is a jquery example of adding the classes to buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').addClass("button");
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  /* foundation button styles */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Im a button</button>
```

Comment: Why the down vote? 3 options of solving the problem... what more do you want?

Comment: got to love the people that view a question, down vote answers without providing feedback or a better solution... well hope my answer helps somewhat anyways

Comment: yeah:) maybe someone will add something more. If not, I will upvote and select one of your methods. Thank you!

Comment: I added an extra one about using the @extend method. this or the javascript options are probably the best (as far as I know). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1) Sass Semantic. @Brad is pointing it.

Use sass to make a semantic markup for your buttons, like this example:

http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b038198f6e0049b8bc3bb1c19231aed0

2) Copy computed styles:

Something like this:

```css
.custom-button-class {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.0625rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-color: #007095;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
          transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
.custom-button-class:hover, .custom-button-class:focus {
  background-color: #007095;
}
.custom-button-class:hover, .custom-button-class:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type="button"] {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.0625rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-color: #007095;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
          transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="button"]:focus {
  background-color: #007095;
}
input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<a class="custom-button-class" href="">hola</a>

<button>hello</button>

<input type="button" value="foundation class button">
```